# What is the meditation benefits of jhana?

Tags: jhana

What are the benefits of the 8 Jhana meditation? Can you list them? I have researched but maybe i haven't looked in the right place? What are some during meditation and after?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jhana is supernormal happiness & also perfect mental clarity in the 4th jhana.

As supernormal happiness, those that reach jhana do not have to depend on anything sensual or worldly for happiness again, such as TV, movies, sex, drugs, music, alcohol, wife, husband, family, fame, money, etc. The mind becomes completely emotionally independent.

As mental clarity, it allows the mind to see more easily through the self-illusion. The self-illusion is the cause of all suffering, whether major or minor. Thus, jhana is the foundation for perfect insight.